# Std::stringstream move assignment not working in gcc

Tags: c++, move, stringstream, move-assignment-operator

An assignment like the following

```
std::stringstream strstr;
strstr = std::stringstream(someString)
```

does give me an error when compiling in gcc:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>& std::basic_stringstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
```

Now, I know that streams apparently cannot be copied and the copy constructor of `std::stringstream` is marked as deleted. However, to my understanding the aforementioned should be a move assignment, not a copy assignment since there is an r-value on the right side of the assignment operator.

Althogh in this case it could probably solve by just using `strstr.str(someString)` instead, I still would be interested in what causes this compiler error. It compiles without problems in VC++ by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was delayed for reasons of ABI compatibilty. They wanted to wait for a major version number change. It is there in the recently released version 5.1: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx

> - movable and swappable iostream classes;